# Changing Type of Equation To Graph Through User Interface

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm new to *Mathematica*. I am trying to create a graph that can change through user interface in more than just the variables. Ideally, I want the user to click a button and have the equation change from a linear equation to an exponential equation, for example, and then change the variables with sliders. I have the sliders, but I'm not sure how to change the equation itself. My code so far is as follows:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a*x+b, {x,-5, 6}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[a*b^x + c, {x, -5, 6}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, 0.01, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TabView[
 {"Linear:  a x + b" -> 
   Manipulate[Plot[a x + b, {x, -5, 6}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
  "Exponential:  a \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(b\), \(x\)]\) + c" -> 
   Manipulate[
    Plot[a b^x + c, {x, -5, 6}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, 1, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]} ]
```

Do you really want `b` to take on negative values in the Exponential function?

You can also try `MenuView`, which may be preferable if you have many functions.

Comment: That's a good point; no, `b` probably doesn't need to take on negative values in the exponential function.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I changed the lower bound for `b` to 0.01 and there were no errors.